# Laravel orderBy back up field incase primary is duplicate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Working on a queuing system that allows users to book appointments.

There is a slight issue at the moment where two appointments can get the same value for a field of 'estimated_booking_time'. This time is used to show when they are coming up.

The problem is that when fetching all appointments the ones with a duplicate estimated_booking_time are then ordered by their ID which (depending on when the appointment was booked) can sometimes be in a reverse order.

Im using carbon to create a diffInMinutes return on another field but the where the ID is the backup order my results are not always correct.

Is there a way to tell Laravel instead to use another field as the backup orderby field when there are duplicate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke `orderBy` multiple times.

`Booking::orderBy('estimated_booking_time', 'ASC')->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get();`

Comment: That is one that I tried just now and works. Wasn't sure if that caused any knock on affects. Will it only orderBy the second if the first is duplicate? The order is very important the second orderBy should only be used as a backup.

Comment: It will first `orderBy` the first argument, then by the following conditions if there are multiple results.